# convert span id text into link and display as text

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The scenario is: User choose a entry from dropDown list. Referring to the relevant entry i will create a new prefix for the webpath existing in . But the problem I have, the  will not interpret as a link part, so the link won't be generated! 
Use Case: If User choose link1 from dropDown-list, the result should be:https://link1//web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp (as link and as text display)

Could you help me how I can reach this?

Many thanks for your help! :)

JS:

```
function output (choice) {


 var index =  choice.selectedIndex;
 var prefix = "";



  if(index == 1) 
prefix = "https://link1";

   else if (index == 2) 
prefix = "https://link2;    

  else if (index == 3) 
prefix = "https://link3";   

  else if (index == 4) 
prefix = "https://link4";   

  else if (index == 5) 
prefix = ""https://link5";



document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = praefix;

}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>

   <form>
    <p>
 <select id = "list" name = "list" onchange ='output(this.form.liste);' >

<option></option>
<option>link1</option>
<option>link2</option>
<option>link3</option>
<option>link4</option>
<option>link5</option>



</select>


</p>

</form>




<a href=<span id = "url"></span>/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp> <span id = "url"></span>    /web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp</a>

</body>
```

Comment: i do not understand your question

Comment: This line: 
<a href=<span id = "url"></span>/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp> <span id = "url"></span>    /web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp</a> 
does not work, because <span id = "url"</span> is not a link-part. But I need this prefix to complete the link! And this link should also display as text!

Comment: are you using any framework? (jquery, prototype, etc)

Comment: and you question is not really clear...

Comment: Due to your formulation, the question is indeed hard to comprehend. But what I don't understand, why don't you simply use <a> tags instead of wanting to 'convert' <span> tags to <a> tags?

Comment: If that's your real HTML then there's no wonder that JavaScript won't work: your `a` element is badly-formed, and you've got two `span` elements with the same `id`. This is invalid (an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document). Correct your HTML, and your syntax errors (you comment on [MrCode's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13612511/82548) that you know what they are) and *then* ask about how to make it work. JavaScript will *not* work with invalid/badly-formed HTML and syntactically invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas +1 the syntax errors are easily fixed. I've added a fiddle showing a better way of coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/JFqrH/3/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <p>
       <select id = "list" name = "list" onchange ='output(this);' >    
          <option></option>
          <option>link1</option>
          <option>link2</option>
          <option>link3</option>
          <option>link4</option>
          <option>link5</option>
       </select>
   </p>
   <a id="url" href="/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp">/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp</a>
   <a id="url1" href="/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp">/web/sso/bw/ostrfer1.jsp</a>
   <a id="url2" href="/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp">/web/sso/bw/ostrfer2.jsp</a>
</form>​
```

JS:

```
function output (choice) {
   var index =  choice.selectedIndex;
   var prefix = "";
   if(index == 1) 
     prefix = "https://link1";    
   else if (index == 2) 
     prefix = "https://link2";        
  else if (index == 3) 
    prefix = "https://link3";       
  else if (index == 4) 
    prefix = "https://link4";       
  else if (index == 5) 
    prefix = "https://link5";    

   updateLink(document.getElementById("url"), prefix);
   updateLink(document.getElementById("url1"), prefix);
   updateLink(document.getElementById("url2"), prefix);
}​
function updateLink(url, prefix) {
   if(!url.getAttribute("postfix")) {// need to save orignal href as it will be replaced later
        url.setAttribute("postfix", url.getAttribute("href"));                
   }
   var postfix = url.getAttribute("postfix");
   url.innerHTML = prefix + postfix;
   url.href = prefix + postfix;    

}
```

You have multiple syntax errors in your code. Plus `a href=<span id = "url"></span>` is nonsence. It can't work. Instead of that you should use attributes (see [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute)/[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)). Also, it is much simpler to use swithc statement instead of if/else. Another thing: `onchange=output(this.form.liste);` - instead of this you can use `onchange=output(this);` as this will already point to your dropdown element there.

Comment: Many Thanks to you FAngel. That was the right answer I was looking for! :)

Comment: Your example works for only one link, but I have a number of links to set prefix+postfix! 
If I copy the statement <a id="url" href="/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp">/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp</a>  for other links, the prefix won't be set!?? Why?

Comment: I have recopied the statement, for example 2 links: 
<a id="url" href="/web/sso/bw/ostreir.jsp">/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp</a> 

<a id="url" href="/vge/ssoweb/bw/hello.jsp">/vge/ssoweb/bw/hello.jsp</a> 
Then he sets only the prefix+postfix for first link/statement!

Comment: That is wrong. You have two items with same ID. That is wrong. document.getElementById will return only the first one. Let me update my answer

Comment: @user1860908 I've added example of usage when each link has own ID, but that is not the best way. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JFqrH/4/). Links are taken by class name there (see additional cross-browser `getElementsByClass` function).

Comment: Is it also possible, to save it in an array or by the statement getElementsByTagName("a"), because <a> is existing in every link-statement. It's not nice to copy the urls for hundred links :(
But with getElementsByTagName I don't know how to set prefix and postfix :(?

Comment: See demo in my previous comment. It will work same way. Just replace `getElementsByClass` with `getElementsByTagName`. There is also another function which will set prefix/postfix correctly

Comment: Thank you FAngel :). But I don't understand the part beginning with ...else{
 getElementsByClass = function(classList, node) {            
          var node = node || document,
          list = node.getElementsByTagName('*'),
          length = list.length, 
//some more code...
Why is this required?

Comment: That is cross-browser code for getElementsByClass if built in browser function is available, than it is used, otherwise - pure JS code to search DOM by class name (for IE mainly)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors that are causing the problem:

First

```
prefix = "https://link2;
                       ^ missing close quote here
```

Second

```
prefix = ""https://link5";
          ^ remove the extra quote here
```

Third

```
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = praefix;
                                           ^ should be prefix
```

Fourth

```
<select id = "list" name = "list" onchange ='output(this.form.liste);' >
                                                              ^ should be list or just 'this'
```

Even with the syntax errors, your code is still not right - it's not good to have a `<span>` within the `href` of an `<a>`.

**[Try this jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gG9bf/)** - I changed the way the code works, it doesn't use the span.

**Full fixed code:**

```
<script>
function output () {

 var index =  this.selectedIndex;
 var prefix = "";
 var suffix = "/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp";

 prefix = "https://" + this.value;

var link = document.getElementById("url");

link.href = prefix + suffix;
link.innerHTML = prefix + suffix;

}

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("list").onchange = output;
}​
</script>

<form>
<p>
 <select id = "list" name = "list" >

<option></option>
<option>link1</option>
<option>link2</option>
<option>link3</option>
<option>link4</option>
<option>link5</option>

</select>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: I know the syntax errors, because i translate it from german into english language. The code worked before, the syntax was also correct ;). But my problem won't be solved :(!!

Comment: thank you for your efforts :). But it's very static. It should be for a number of links!

Comment: This is not static at all, what planet are you on? This works for all of the links :)

Comment: I've got a hundred of links and in your code example i have to copy the statement var suffix = "link...";  more than hundred times :(

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty unclear, does this work?

```
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = prefix + document.getElementById("url").innerHTML;
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. The command ... <span id ="url"</span> refers to the relevant prefix!! But this part cannot interpret as link in 
<a href=...</a> :(

Answer (score 0):

You could store the this snippet:

```
/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp
```

as a constant like so:

```
var uri = "/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp";
```

Then when the user selects the link you could append it like so:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("url");
elem.setAttribute('href', prefix + uri);
```

This should update the "href" attribute of the anchor tag with the new url.

I setup a test example so you can see it in action in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brYdu/). If you inspect the link with the browsers developer tools you can see that the href (originally an empty string "") has now been updated after executing the code to be "https://link1/web/sso/bw/ostrfer.jsp".

Hope this helps.